# Create sequence of time differences based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, posixct

TLDR: Need to create sequence of distinct rows but having issues with time sequences

I have a list of data frames, each looking similar to this (df1):

```
sector1 = data.frame(date = rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2001-01-01 00:00:00"),format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
                                           as.POSIXct("2001-01-01  04:00:00"),format = "%Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S","hour"),
                                length.out = 7), order = rep(1,length.out = 7))


sector2 = data.frame(date = rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2001-02-01 04:30:00"),format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
                                           as.POSIXct("2001-02-01  06:00:00"),format = "%Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S","hour"),
                                length.out = 7), order = rep(2,length.out = 7))


sector3 = data.frame(date = rep(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct("2001-03-01 06:30:00"),format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S",
                                           as.POSIXct("2001-03-01  10:00:00"),format = "%Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S","hour"),
                                length.out = 7), order = rep(3,length.out = 7))


# binding sectors
df1 = rbind(sector1,sector2,sector3) %>% distinct(date,order)
```

Basically they have an "order" and a date (as well as other columns). What I need is to extract a row sequence of the earliest date at which the order changes from one state to another (ultimately only returning unique order; thus in this case I would expect 3 rows) and then calculate how long it took for that state change to occur. For the purposes of this example I'll do things on a single dataframe, but whatever the answer is be aware that it will be applied using lapply to a list.

Setting up a repex dataframe:

```
#adding spurious row with order 3 but date that precedes order 2
df1[12,] = data.frame(date = as.POSIXct("2001-02-01 03:30:00"), order = 3)

# extracting rows of length(unique(df1$order))
df2 = df1 %>% group_by(order) %>% slice_min(order_by = date, n = 1) 

df2 =  df2 %>% arrange(date)
```

Originally, I achieved this, albeit quite slowly, using:

```
df2 %>% group_by(order) %>% slice_min(order_by = date, n = 1) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>%  mutate(time_between = as.numeric(date-lag(date), units = 'hours'))
```

What the above is doing is grouping by order then slicing the first row (mostly this corresponds to the earlies time, as typically this is in time order). Then I'm calculating the time between each order change.

This is the result:

```
                 date order time_between
1 2001-01-01 00:00:00     1           NA
2 2001-02-01 04:30:00     2        748.5
3 2001-02-01 03:30:00     3         -1.0
```

Although the above works in the majority of cases (it's quite slow), it has issues when a date from a subsequent order (3 in the above example) is timestamped prior to a preceding order (2 in the above case). This means that I have a negative time value (-1.0) which doesn't make sense.

What I would like to do is instead of merely grouping by order then slicing first row is some sort of logical operation where if the date/time of the row that was going to be extracted precedes the one of the previous order it gets discarded and the first row after the time is chosen, in this case it would be `2001-03-01 06:30:00  3`

```
                 date order time_between
1 2001-01-01 00:00:00     1           NA
2 2001-02-01 04:30:00     2        748.5
3 2001-03-01 06:30:00     3        674.0
```

As mentioned, I was doing the above across a list of dataframes, so implementing like this:

```
lapply(list1, function(x) {x %>% group_by(order) %>% slice_min(order_by = date, n = 1) %>% ungroup()})
lapply(list1, function(x) {x %>% mutate(time_between = as.numeric(date-lag(date), units = 'hours'))})
```

Additional example dataframe:

```
df1 = data.frame(datetime = as.POSIXct(c("2019-04-11 21:46:55",
                                     "2019-04-13 00:19:23",
                                     "2019-04-15 01:20:41",
                                     "2019-04-15 04:18:12",
                                     "2019-04-23 00:50:45",
                                     "2019-04-22 08:44:41",
                                     "2019-04-24 05:54:17",
                                     "2019-04-23 07:21:36")), order = c(1,3,4,5,6,7,9,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly which step is slowing the process but starting from `df1` you can do keep one row for each date using `distinct` and then subtract time using `lag` and `as.numeric`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd_hms(date))  %>%
  arrange(order, date) %>%
  distinct(order, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(time_between = as.numeric(date - lag(date), units = 'hours'))

#                 date order  only_date time_between
#1 2001-01-01 00:00:00     1 2001-01-01           NA
#2 2001-02-01 04:30:00     2 2001-02-01        748.5
#3 2001-03-01 06:30:00     3 2001-03-01        674.0
```

Obviously for list of dataframes use it with `lapply`/`map` :

```
lapply(list1, function(x) {
 x %>%
    mutate(date = lubridate::ymd_hms(date))  %>%
    arrange(order, date) %>%
    distinct(order, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(time_between = as.numeric(date - lag(date), units = 'hours'))
})
```

Comment: Ronak. Thanks for the input. I should have been clearer. It's not just the date but also the time that I'm interested in arranging. Thus a row for a specific order may have an earlier time (than the row for the previous order), if this is the case I want to ignore this and take the first row to have a time after that. In other words I need order to be sequential and time to be sequential, as then I can successfully calculate the difference. Sorry it's quite confusing.

Comment: The slow part is where I grouped by order and sliced min()

Comment: @Dasr Ok, so would adding `arrange(date) %>%` before `distinct` help? So that you get the min time in for each date always when you use `distinct` ?

Comment: Ok, I'll try and describe using objectives:

1) I need to extract all distinct orders appearing in the dataframe (in this example 3)
2) I need one row for each order to appear in the filtered dataframe
3) I need time difference to be calculated between the row before and row after (excluding first row for which it is impossible)
4) each row should be representative of the earliest time that particular order was present in the unfiltered dataframe, unless that time precedes the previous row, if this is the case it should look lower down in the original df and choose another row with ...

Comment: the same order but a later time

Comment: This is a simple example but imagine a dataframe with 20 distinct orders and 1000 rows for each order. From this I would only extract 20 rows.

Comment: Instead of `distinct` date, you want distinct `order`. This is the only thing which I found I was doing wrong in my answer. :/ I have corrected it now, is that what you want?

Comment: So I've tried using your code in my situation (larger dataframe) and what happens is that in instances where the time on a higher order (i.e. later in sequence) is earlier then previous row (earlier order) it puts that in instead one that has a later time. I can get around this by `arrange(date,order)` but then order is incorrect. What I need it to do is instead of choosing first by order it chooses first by order that has a later time....

Comment: I am not sure if I understand. Can you provide a reproducible example similar to your original dataset?

Comment: Added a dataframe which behaves like the big one I think.

Comment: Basically, instead of the row that has datetime `2019-04-22 08:44:41  7` the one that should be in the modified dataframe is `2019-04-23 07:21:36    7` as this comes after in time. But currently when I run things I get the first and then get a negative time_between value.

Comment: How do you decide to keep which row? earlier or later? You can keep the later row if you use `arrange(order, desc(date))`

Comment: That won't do as it will take from the bottom of the pile. I need it to take the first instance where the time comes after. So, if there are three rows with order 7 `2019-04-22 08:44:41     7; 2019-04-23 07:21:36     7; 2019-04-23 07:20:00     7` it should take the 07:20 as this is the first instance in which the time is after the order 6 row but not the last (which is what it would do if I just arrange(order, desc(date)). Sorry I don't think I can be clearer...